# Extract a Word from String Containing a Specific Multiple Words

Tags: excel, excel-formula

"I'm setting up a pivot in excel, and want to extract specific words from a data set of text.

I have tried using the below formula to extract one particular word, but want to nest the multiple formula to extract other words as well

```
=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",REPT(" ",99)),MAX(1,FIND("Evaluation",SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",REPT(" ",99)))-50),99))
```

The above formula works but only for one word. I want to create nested formula to search first word or second word or third...

[image: Formula]

Comment: Have a look over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56672807/trouble-retrieving-the-matched-criteria-using-search-function-in-excel/56673081#56673081). Is that what you are trying?

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to search an array for a a substring, if that substring matches any words in a list, and if so, return the matched substring, as in the post suggested by JvdV, use the formula below, which I have modified.

I recommend, in a different worksheet, add a table with a list of the words you want to find, like this.  Highlight the range of cells, including the header, then Home > Format as Table > pick a table style and give it a name.  This table's name is "t_WordsToFind" (so I can easily identify it in other functions later).  You may want to also put your primary data into a table as well.  My go-to name is usually "t_Data".  Now, instead of worrying about column numbers/letters, you have the user-friendly column headers you started with which makes reading the formula much easier.  Your table ranges will also automatically expand when addtl data is added, so row numbers don't need to be referenced any more either.

[image]

If you don't have your data in tables, use this version of the formula, and remember to update your range parameters when data is added.  B2 is the first cell to be searched, D2:D4 is the list of words to look for, copy the formula down.  I do prefer not to use IFERROR as it includes many different types of errors that I may need to know about, like if I misspelled the function name, for example.  If you simply need to have an alternative in the event no matches are return and your function is valid, I recommend IFNA.

```
IFNA(LOOKUP(1,1/COUNTIF(B2,"*"&$D$2:$D$4&"*"),$D$2:$D$4),"")
```

If you do use tables for your data and lookup tables (you are very wise) and here is the formula version to use (below).  In this example, @[Search This Column] is the the equivalent to B2 and t_WordsToFind[Find This] is the table name and column name of words to look for, but it's much more legible, and doesn't need to be copied down or manually expanded in the future.

```
IFNA(LOOKUP(1,1/COUNTIF([@[Search This Column]],"*"&t_WordsToFind[Find This]&"*"),t_WordsToFind[Find This]),"")
```

[image]

Even wiser still, assuming this is a perpetual need, would be to use power query/power pivot, but I don't want you to go into TMI overload.

Also, your pivot table range will be nice and easy, "t_Data".